# AngularJS and javascript oop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oop

i'm developing on large frontend app in angularjs.

I wonder if this approach can be used in angularjs and, if there are holes, performance problems or other disadvantages.

**first code in controller**

```
 function ServiceHandler() {

         var self = this;
         self.init();

    }
    ServiceHandler.prototype = {
         constructor : ServiceHandler,
         request : undefined,
         init : function(){

           self.callService();

         },
         createRequest : function() {

             self.request = {};
             self.request = Service.getRequest();

         },
         callService : function() {

             self.iAmLoading = true;
             self.createRequest();
             Service.callService(self.request).then(function(response) {
                  self.iAmLoading = false;
                  if (angular.isDefined(response) && angular.isDefined(response.data)) {
                       self.handleRequest(response);
                  }
              }, function(error) {
                  self.handleSystemError(error);
              });

         },
         handleRequest : function(response) {

             if (angular.isUndefined(self.response)) {
                    self.response = {};
             }
             if (angular.isUndefined(response.data)) {
                    self.handleError(response);
             }else {

             self.response = response.data;

             }
          },
          handleSytemError : function(error) {
              // show 404
          },
          handleError : function(response) {
              // think on what to do with your response
          }
    }
```

**then i bound it with controller init method**

```
$scope.init(){
    $scope.myServiceHandler = new ServiceHandler(); // in this manner i call the service first time because the constructor call the init method on my ServiceHandler object also

}
```

**i bound it in dom with**

```
<div ng-controller="myController" ng-init="init()">
```

**and in the html i can refer to my response obect with:**

```
{{myServiceHandler.response.myResponseProperty}}
```

**and if i want a botton for a recall to my service i can do:**

```
<button ng-click='myServiceHandler.callService()'></button>
```

Personally I think the advantage of this structure is the organization of the code and that this structure seems to be more ojects oriented  and more fun to achieve

let me know what do you think.
thanks and regards
Antonio

PS - i write this code for this question, i write it on the fly, i think it's work, but i'm not 100% surely, it's not tested :) i have wrote other Controllers like this, they are in Production now and seems to work fine.

PS2 - exuse me for my English, i'm studing it now and i have only 1500 xp on Duolingo for now :) :)

Comment: This question seems more suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, if you go with this approach, you can use [`Angular's Service Provider`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers). Except you actually want to create new `object` each time the controller that has scope with code `$scope.myServiceHandler = new ServiceHandler();` is called. I doubt that your `ServiceHandler` constructor is something that necessary, because with `Anggular's controllers` approach I prefer using singletons rather than constructor, because controller usually called more than one times.

Comment: Great I think, but it become `singleton` isn't? So I still prefer using `Angular's services` to work with singletons. It's more readable, also still acceptable in OOP point of view. Just like modern languages like Scala, Ruby, Python, etc. Object can be created just to make a single object.

But it just a taste of preferences I think.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use a factory instead of hard coded service handler on the controller, usually a service is code and functionality that you would reuse over the app, so if you are developing a huge front end app I would locale that service into a factory.

After that you would inject the service into the controllers in where it is needed.

Advantages of creating a service/factory:

- Easy to test
- Easy to maintain and scale
- Is more Object oriented
- Single instance for all yours controllers ( better memory usage )
- Is more elegant.. ( if your boss is a elegant code guy )

  Imagine you need this serviceHandler in other controller, and at the end you have this hard coded in each controller.. if you have to change/extend the serviceHandler you would have to do that for each controller, but if you use a factory you would do that once in the service definition.

If you create the serviceHandler with a factory your controller would look like:

```
theApp.controller('controller', ['$scope','serviceHandler', function($scope, serviceHandler){
    serviceHandler.init(); // is practically the same of ng init
    $scope.recall = serviceHandler.callService;
}]);
```

This way you would modify the serviceHandler and you would inject this serviceHandler in each controller that would use it.. your code for the service is ok, but is better to create the service in a factory/service/provider instead of a hard coded service in each controller , since this are single instance and you would reuse code, and would save memory.